# Fitting Image on Android WebView

Tags: java, android, html, image, webview

I'm using WebView and i want to display an image inside it.

I want to fit the image in webview. (The image becomes so big so i have to scroll horizontally)

I show images like this (if it matters): `<img src="path" alt="">`

What i have tried:

```
WebView content = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
content.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%;} 
</style>" + CONTENT, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

But when i use this method, the images are not visible. Only texts

Also i tried this:

```
   WebSettings settings = preview.getSettings();
   settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

It works but it's not good since it zoom out the webview and the texts become unreadable.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use this code it will allow you to fit all the image in the webview

```
String imageUrl = "<Put here the image>";
        String html = "<html><head>" +
                "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=no\">"+
                "<style>\n" +
                "html,body{ margin:auto;}"+
                "#image{\n" +
                "    width: 100vw;\n" +
                "    height: 100vh;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "</style></head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<img id=\"image\" src=\""+imageUrl+"\" alt =\"no image\">\n" +
                "</body></html>";
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,html,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```